# Why does float behave different with <div> vs <p>?

Tags: html, css

css:

```
.floatleft {
  float:left;
}
```

Why is this:

```
<div>
 <div class="floatleft">Hello</div>
 <div>World</div>
</div>
```

different than this:

```
<div>
  <p class="floatleft">Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't add ANY CSS, so you won't get a real answer. The float parameters are in the CSS, "floatleft" is just a class (which probably contains `float:left`, but we can't know for sure...).

Comment: Ok, i made my question clearer. Thank you!

Comment: No CSS for DIVs or P tags? - then there is NO difference, except maybe padding/margin, depending on the browsers default styles. But that has nothing to do with floats.

Comment: Hi Devin, you need to explain/show exactly how the <div> and <p> are behaving differently for you. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried (show your code!) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the two blocks you presented is the `agent stylesheet`. Paragraphs will have default margins, that's why they may look different. But appart from the agent stylesheet, the 2 blocks are exactly the same and should look exacly the same.

JSFiddle provided by Derek: [jsfiddle.net/7mnybj3u/1](http://jsfiddle.net/7mnybj3u/1)

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle displaying your answer (but margin not padding): https://jsfiddle.net/7mnybj3u/1/

Comment: Thanks @DerekStory. I've updated the answer and your JSFiddle really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your absolute best reference to questions like this is "inspect page" which most browsers have these days.  You can analyze the behavior of any element this way.

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag has a **default margin** that makes floating work diferently, if you reset the margin the floating will work ok!

```
p { margin:0 }
```